# How to set zero in the cells if the cells are empty using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 3 sheets inside:

- Starting Date and Ending Date in `Sheet1` (1st screenshot)
- A database in `Sheet2` (2nd screenshot)
- Filtered data in `Sheet3` based on the date in `Sheet1` (3rd screenshot)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a script that copy the data from `Sheet2` to `Sheet3` based on the date in `Sheet1`. I want the script to be able to put a zero in the empty space if it is detected instead of leaving it as blank.

For example, in the 2nd screenshot above, there is no value in `Row 8` for Group 4 and Group 6, so I want the script to be able to put a zero in Group 4 and Group 6 for `Row 8` when the data is copied to `Sheet3`.

I managed to achieve this but some how there will be zero in `Row 9` as well (shown in the 3rd screenshot). There should be no zero in `Row 9` since the date in `Sheet1` is only from December-20 to February-21 (3 months). May I know how should I modified my script so that I'm able to eliminate the zero in `Row 9`? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is my script:

```
Sub extractdata()

Dim LastRow As Long, erow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim mydate As Date

LastRow2 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet3.Range("B6:H" & LastRow2).ClearContents

LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To LastRow

    mydate = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)
    
    If mydate >= Sheet1.Cells(7, 19) And mydate <= Sheet1.Cells(8, 19) Then
    erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(i, 2), Sheet2.Cells(i, 57)).Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(erow, 2)
    End If
    
    For j = 3 To 8
        If IsEmpty(Sheet3.Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
        Sheet3.Cells(i, j) = 0
        End If
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

### Edit

```
Sub extractdata()

Dim LastRow As Long, erow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim mydate As Date

LastRow2 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet3.Range("B6:H" & LastRow2).ClearContents

LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To LastRow

    mydate = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)
    
    If mydate >= Sheet1.Cells(7, 19) And mydate <= Sheet1.Cells(8, 19) Then
    erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(i, 2), Sheet2.Cells(i, 57)).Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(erow, 2)
    End If
Next i

ZeroIsteadBlank
End Sub
```

I call the function after `For loop`, but this is what I get:

[image]

`Row 9` still exist with bunch of zero with additional date in Cell `B9`

Comment: You could just copy the dates over, then have a vlookup and use IF statements in the table to return the data you want

Comment: Step through your loop iterations and see if you can establish where the logic is adding the extra row of 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use this code at the end. Iterating during the copying code is waste of time and Excel resources:

```
Sub ZeroIsnteadBlank()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngEmpty As Range, LastRow2 As Long
  
  Set sh = Sheet3 
  LastRow2 = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '+ 1 for an extra row...

  On Error Resume Next 'Otherwise, the following line will return an error in case of no empty cells...
   Set rngEmpty = sh.Range("C6:H" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   If Not rngEmpty Is Nothing Then
        rngEmpty.value = 0
   Else
        MsgBox "No empty cells..."
   End If
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

In order to avoid the case of an empty cell of the column C:C (C8 in your example), it should be good to calculate `LastRow2` for two columns and choose the bigger one...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thanks for your reply, I tried to add your code into the script, but I still get zero in `Row 9`. May I know where is my mistake? I edited my question attached with new script and screenshot.

Comment: @weizer: OK. Let us understand WHERE is the problem... So, after running your code, please do not run the above one before checking on which row C:C column values finishes. Is it possible to have an empty cell in C8, as I written in my answer? Please, comment `ZeroIsteadBlank` line. I can see (now) that I lost a letter to make the name relevant... :)

Comment: @weizer: In fact, I looked to your recent picture and the problem becomes evident. You have  a row starting with `January-00` (strange label, anyhow...) in column B:B, but the code calculates the last row based on C:C column last value. I do not know how that `January-00` appeared. I can only imagine that my code place a zero and being formatted as `Date` it shows that strange string... Am I right? If you need to start placing zeros, redefine the range to start from C:C column: `sh.Range("C6:H" & LastRow2)` instead of `sh.Range("B6:H" & LastRow2)`... I adapted the code in this suggested way.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation:), after removing `+1` in `LastRow2`, it works well now.

Comment: @weizer: Glad I could help! But looking to your initial picture I understood that the first empty row should also have 0 instead blank cells...